# Can i style box model width when hover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im using stwiter bootstrap to design my products page with multi product , so im using fluid layout in bootstrap freamwork to design a box product and this so small , i whan when hover in a box product this box with be than lager and postion top of all the box , see image below , can any help , thank so much

here is my css and html

```
    <div class="box-product row-fluid">
            <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="MacBook" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">MacBook</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $589.50                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
  </div>
            <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="iPhone" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">iPhone</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $120.68                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $236.99                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
           </div>
            <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="Sony VAIO" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">Sony VAIO</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $1,177.00                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
            </div>

    </div>
           <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="Sony VAIO" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">Sony VAIO</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $1,177.00                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
             </div>

    </div>
              <div class="span2" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img alt="Sony VAIO" src=""></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="">Sony VAIO</a></div>
            <div class="price">
                $1,177.00                  </div>
                    <div class="cart"><input type="button" class="button" onclick="" value="Add to Cart"></div>
  </div>

    </div>
```

my css below

```
   .box-product {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
    }
   .box-product > div {
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .box-product > div:hover{
 z-index: 10;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius:5px;
box-sizing:border-box;

box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-o-box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border: 5px solid #FFA500;
    }
     .box-product .image {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

i want when hover in product box , this box will arrange bring to front of the all and width so lager
[image like to my mean](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54153922/hover.fw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scale() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

Example

```
  style:hover {
      ...
      transform: scale(2);
     -moz-transform:scale(2); 
     -webkit-transform:scale(2);
     -o-transform:scale(2);
     -ms-transform: scale(2);
      ...
  }
```

- Scale(2) - It increases the size of the div up to twice of its original size on mouse hover on the div.
- You can change these values according to your own choice